# IDs with multiple records - how to find the record I need?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table (Job Types) containing an ID (for the person completing the job), the year the job was completed (YYYY) and the Jobtype Id.

```
|ID |   YEAR    | JOBTYPE|
|123A|  2017    |1
|124A|  2017    |2
|125A|  2016    | 2
|126A|  2017    |3
|123A|  2017    |2
|125A|  2016    |2
```

What I need is to find the IDs of everyone that completed only Jobtype 2 in 2017. In the above table, that would **only be 124A**. (125A completed Jobtype 2 in 2016; 123A did 1 and 2; etc.). Sidenote: it would not matter if an ID completed multiple Jobtype 2s in 2017 - I'd want those records.

How can I do this? I've tried a few NOT EXISTS queries but I think I'm getting stuck because 1 ID could potentially have a number of records against it. I'm guessing I need to somehow combine the data so every ID has one record, and then query it that way? Or am I missing something really obvious? I'm working in SQL Server 2012 and just cannot see a way forward. (Apologies if I'm missing something really simple, but I don't normally have cause to do anything much beyond select statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a query to get all of the ids where there were jobtype completions that are NOT 2 in 2017, then select only records where the `id` isn't in the results of that first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE jobtype = 2 and year = 2017
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE jobtype <> 2 and Year=2017)
```

Comment: Aah! NOT IN! Thank you so much - I was obviously trying to create a solution that was far more complicate than it needed to be!

Answer (score 0):

You want information per ID, so `GROUP BY` ID. Then filter in `HAVING`. E.g.:

```
select id
from jobtypes
having min(year) = 2017
   and max(year) = 2017
   and min(jobtype) = 2
   and max(jobtype) = 2
;
```

The criteria can easily be adjusted. For instance others understood your criteria to mean: one or more 2017|2 records and no other record in 2017, whereas I understood it as one or more 2017|2 records and no other record at all. In case you want to look at 2017 only:

```
select id
from jobtypes
where year = 2017
having min(jobtype) = 2
   and max(jobtype) = 2
;
```

Whatever criteria to apply, the table has to be read just once.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work,

```
SELECT * FROM #Your_Table A WHERE JobType=2 AND Year=2017 AND NOT EXISTS(
SELECT ID FROM (SELECT *,Row_number() Over(Partition by ID Order by ID) AS Row_Num FROM #Your_Table)B
WHERE JobType=2 and Row_num>1 and B.ID=A.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM #test a
left join (Select id from #test where jobtype<>2 and [Year] = 2017) b on a.id=b.id
where jobtype=2 and year=2017 and b.id is null
```